# By-name type parameters

Tags: scala, pass-by-name

Imagine I have the following class definition:

```
class Foo[T]
```

and I want to do the following

```
def bar(x:Foo[ =>Int ]):Int = ???
```

But compiler fails with "no by-name parameter type allowed here"

How can I use a by-name type as type parameter for a generic method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You’ll have to provide your own lazy wrapper. Something like this:

```
class Lazy[T](wrp: => T) {
  lazy val value: T = wrp
}
```

and then:

```
def bar(x: Foo[Lazy[T]]): Int = ???
```

Comment: what about `class Lazy[T](val value: =>T)`? No need to repeat the value holder.

Comment: @pedrofurla. not allowed (val parameters may not be call by name). And if it was, at what times would value be supposed to be initialized?

Comment: Weird. Didn't know that. I supposed they would be init-ed at first call.